# error when adding rsync:// before the address

Tags: rsync

I'm getting error whenever I try to connect to the host with `rsync://` in front.

```
rsync -P testfile.test rsync://user@192.168.1.2:12000
rsync: failed to connect to 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(127) [sender=3.1.3]
```

And if I remove the `rsync://` in front of the address it works:

```
rsync -P testfile.test user@192.168.1.2:12000
testfile.test
              8 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to solve it? I need to connect using a software that has the `rsync://` hardcoded into its code.

Answer (score 0):

The version without `rsync://` uses the `ssh` command to establish a connection.
The version with `rsync://` uses the rsync protocol.

You can

- configure `rsync` on the server to listen to your port.
- Replace `rsync` on the client with a script that removes `rsync://` from the arguments and calls the real `rsync`.

Comment: The server has rsyncd configured and running and I tried connecting to a module which was read okay. Is there any particular configuration to set the rsyncd to use its protocol instead of ssh?

Comment: Yes, see the rsyncd man page. rsyncd never listens for SSH. Maybe you just use the wrong port?

Comment: Found the solution: I had to simply start the server with sudo because the port configured was > 1000.

Comment: Ports above 1023 (i.e. 1024 to 65535) shouldn't need root permissions to bind. They might need root permissions to perform their tasks, though